# split string with preg_split

Tags: php, regex

I have a long string(in one line), and i want to split it using regex.

the string:

```
2013-10-28;;0;;0;;0.00;;0;;0;;0;;0.0;;0;;0;;0;;0.00;;0.00
2013-10-29;;0;;0;;0.00;;0;;0;;0;;0.0;;0;;0;;0;;0.00;;0.00
2013-10-30;;0;;0;;0.00;;0;;0;;0;;0.0;;0;;0;;0;;0.00;;0.00
2013-10-31;;0;;0;;0.00;;0;;0;;0;;0.0;;0;;0;;0;;0.00;;0.00
```

i tried using explode like so:

```
explode("2013",$string);
```

but it removes the delimiter.

so how can i split it using regex?

thanks :)

output should look like:

```
[0]=>2013-10-28;;0;;0;;0.00;;0;;0;;0;;0.0;;0;;0;;0;;0.00;;0.00
[1]=>2013-10-29;;0;;0;;0.00;;0;;0;;0;;0.0;;0;;0;;0;;0.00;;0.00
[2]=>2013-10-30;;0;;0;;0.00;;0;;0;;0;;0.0;;0;;0;;0;;0.00;;0.00
[3]=>2013-10-31;;0;;0;;0.00;;0;;0;;0;;0.0;;0;;0;;0;;0.00;;0.00
```

Comment: split on what? what's your expected output?

Comment: i added how the output should look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$lines = array();
$lines = explode("2013",$string);
foreach($lines as $key => $value)
{
   $data = array()
   $data = explode(";;",$value);
   $lines[$key]['data'] = $data
}
```